# Expo push notifications with custom sound on bare workflow

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm working on push notifications using Expo version 41 - bare workflow (in the documentation is written that custom sounds are working only on this workflow). I want to use custom sound. Right now it works for local notification:

```
async function schedulePushNotification() {
  await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: {
      title: "Test notification",
      body: 'Test notification body',
      sound: 'sound.wav', // Android 8.0-
    },
    trigger: {
      seconds: 2,
      channelId: 'sound', // Android 8.0+
    },
  });
}
```

As you can see I have created new channel with id: sound:

```
Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('sound', {
  name: 'sound',
  importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.HIGH,
  sound: 'sound.wav', // <- Android 8.0+
});
```

Almost identical like in the documentation:

> https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#setting-custom-notification-sounds

I use `setNotificationChannelAsync` in useEffect hook after `getExpoPushTokenAsync` (actually copy paste from the documentation)

```
useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setExpoPushToken(token));

    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
      setNotification(notification);
    });

    responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);



async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;
  if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
    const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
    finalStatus = status;
  }
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
    return;
  }
  token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;

  Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('sound', {
    name: 'sound',
    importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    sound: 'sound.wav', // Android 8.0+
  });

  return token;
}
```

The `schedulePushNotification` method is run on button press. After 2 seconds I get a notification with my sound. Cool. When I'm trying to do the same with the `Push notifications tool`

> https://expo.io/notifications

I received a notification with a default sound. It looks like the channel doesn't work.

I tried to send it using `expo-server-sdk-java` also.

> https://github.com/jav/expo-server-sdk-java

```
ExpoPushMessage expoPushMessage = new ExpoPushMessage();
expoPushMessage.setTo(List.of(token));
expoPushMessage.setTitle("Test Notification API JAVA");
expoPushMessage.setBody("Body");
expoPushMessage.setChannelId("sound");
//expoPushMessage.setSound(new ExpoMessageSound(true, "default", 0L));
```

The `setSound` method throwing an exception when name is different than `default`.

I testing it on Android with version 6.1 and 5.0.

Do any of you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Are you find any solution? Can you share?